# icon cannot show in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

icon cannot show in actionbar, this is my search.xml in menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_orange_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Message"/>

</menu>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQVXn.png

but, it cannot show in the app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLHAP.png

this is fragment_home.xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:titleTextColor="#007FFF"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:title="IFUNPOT" />
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:id="@+id/recy_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
```

this is Homefragment.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

this is MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

so....where is problem?

who knows where has problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have forgotten to use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

If you use toolbar, you might have to set up the toolbar in your activity as well in your activity's onCreate `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.